# pdfLaTeX disapeared from kile

Tags: pdftex, kile

Yesterday, I was happily compiling with pdfLaTeX in kile on my kubuntu 14.4, but today, pdfLaTeX is gone from kile. What happened, how do I get it back?

pdflatex still seems to be installed:

```
$ pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.1.1
Copyright 2013 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.2.49; using libpng 1.2.50
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with poppler version 0.24.5
```

Also compiling with

```
$ pdflatex mydocument.tex
```

worked fine.

Can I reset kile to "factory settings" somehow?

Comment: Is it gone from the Build | Compile Menu as well? If it is still there, you may have accidentally altered your toolbar (has happened to me before...).

Comment: What do you mean by 'gone'? Where was it before that it now isn't?

Comment: No, it is not in the Build | Compile Menu. Yes, it was there before and now it's gone.

Comment: What is in that menu? Is it empty? Is everything else still there? Settings > Configure Kile > Tools > Build. Is there an entry for it still in the list? On the right, there is a tab 'Menu' which lets you add entries to the menus. It should say 'Compile'. If not, can you set it there? If you haven't customised your tools, you could also try 'Restore Default Tools'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close Kile, then go to folder `/home/{USER_NAME}/.kde/share/apps/kile/` and remove or rename the file `kileui.rc`. Reopen Kile and check if it solves your problem.

Another option is to go to `Settings > Configure Kile > Tools > Build` and click on `Restore Default Tools...` on the right.

Comment: The second option is what worked for me, by the way.

Comment: @user49283 The first one is for the missing `Settings` option in the Kile's menu. Sometimes it gets hidden with no reason, especially when you customized it.